# A version of \includeonly for \input

Tags: input, include

I have a pretty long paper that is getting sluggish to compile. Different sections are imported with `\input`. I'd like to have something like `\includeonly` but that works on `\input` rather than `\include` commands (`\input` works better for the paper as it does not start sections on new pages, etc.).

A reasonable option would be to use `\include` for the draft and swap back later, but thought I would ask here first if there is a command like `\includeonly` for `\input`. (By the way, I tried `\includeonly` combined with `\input` but indeed it doesn't work.)

Comment: You could use something like `\let\myinput\include` in the preamble and then change it to `\let\myinput\input` for the final version. If you don't want to risk patching internal commands.

Comment: I don't really get though why this question is a duplicate of the other question? I understand from the nice flashy graphic on the other question why the answer that was once here is not perhaps the best solution, but I am left with the question of how best to omit inputs in that case (the other question does not address this at all). @cfr, that is a reasonable solution, thanks!

Comment: I agree. This is certainly NOT a duplicate of the other question. If it is to be marked as a duplicate, it should be a duplicate of the question linked from the one it is marked as currently. I can only think David marked it as a duplicate on the grounds that the answer is the same, but even that strikes me as incorrect. For one thing, you're open to *other* solutions than eliminating `\clearpage` from `\include` so 'don't do this' may apply to Alan Munn's answer, but it needn't apply to all answers to this question.

Comment: That is, if it is a duplicate, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209065/3186474.

Comment: But that question isn't on TeX SE so I don't know it can be marked as a duplicate here.

Comment: @cfr: Yeah, we'll have to write an answer here.

Comment: It's hard to imagine a *paper* that's getting sluggish to compile. You should isolate the part that slow down the process: is the paper graphic intensive?

Comment: @Werner The `newclude` package hasn't been updated for 20 years and the doc says it's “in development”. I don't think it does what it claims to.

Comment: @egreg, good point. Yes there's about 15 tikz graphics in there, but for some reason it also compiles about ten times before finishing (`pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex`). Not sure why but happy to approach it per the question.